# how to select items that concatenation of two rows is like input

Tags: php, mysql, concatenation

i have mysql table, users: (id, first_name, last_name, ....)

i'd like to do something like this pseudo query

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE first_name.' '.last_name = 'john doe' LIMIT 10")
```

I Want to do this cause i have lots of trouble spliting the string (then i don't know in what order is user typing'

This is my current, not working very good

```
$phrase = explode(' ',$term);
$last_name = '';
if($phrase[1] != '')
    $last_name= " OR last_name LIKE '%".$phrase[1]."%'";
$qstring = "SELECT usuarios.first_name,usuarios.last_name,
                    usuarios.id as id
            FROM usuarios
            WHERE first_name LIKE '%".$phrase[0]."%' OR last_name LIKE '%".$phrase[0]."%' $last_name LIMIT 5";
```

Any suggestion to achieve this (by concatenating at query or spliting at php) would be very apreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can concatenate in a MySQL query using [`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_concat):

```sql
SELECT * FROM users WHERE CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name) = 'john doe' LIMIT 10
```

In your code this would become:

```sql
SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name) LIKE '%{$phrase[0]}%' LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, id
FROM usuarios
WHERE CONCAT(first_name, last_name) LIKE '%$phrase[0]%' LIMIT 5
```